# How to get the content type or extension of file uploaded into an Amazon S3 Bucket in Java Spring boot?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, amazon-s3

hey anyone worked on Amazon S3 bucket...can anyone tell me how to get the content type of a particular object uploaded into the bucket?

I tried converting the object again into an file and getting the extension but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content type of a particular object uploaded into an Amazon S3 bucket, you can use the **AWS SDK for Java v2**. You can use the AWS SDK for Java v2 in a Spring BOOT project.

To perform this use case, you can use the following code example. When you run this and the object is a .jpeg, the output is:

The object content type is image/jpeg

Java code:

```
public class GetObjectContentType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <bucketName> <keyName>>\n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket name. \n\n"+
            "    keyName - The key name. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        getContentType(s3,bucketName,keyName);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectcontenttype.main]
    public static void getContentType (S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName) {

        try {
            HeadObjectRequest objectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            HeadObjectResponse objectHead = s3.headObject(objectRequest);
            String type = objectHead.contentType();
            System.out.println("The object content type is "+type);

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectcontenttype.main]
}
```

This code example can be found in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) here:

[Determine the existence and content type of an object in an Amazon S3 bucket using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_HeadObject_section.html)

Comment: Thank you this worked for me.
Though I just want to mention that these method will only work with dependency of AWS SDK of JAVA V2 not with AWS SDK of JAVA V1.

Comment: AWS Java V1 is not longer best practice as specified in this Github page - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples. I am glad it worked for you!